# Consumers had reset the log-end-offset to the offset that is already processed after broker restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When we had to restart Kafka broker in our prod env, we had observed that consumers of a specific consumer group had created a lag even when there is none before our restart.

Could you please help me understand the root cause of this problem.

Please let me know if you guys need more information to understand this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What exactly you mean by 'lag' ? You mean some messages were consumed even when your consumer was down ?

Comment: when we run the below command we see the pending requests for a consumer in the LAG column.                                                                      ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group groupName.

Comment: So lag means a given consumer group consumed data for a given topic ( or set of topic)  , but then it got disconnected , but some producer was producing messages in it . Those extra messages are lag. They should get consumed once your consumer comes up with same " consumer group name "